# How to use libmysql with Qt in windows?

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, qt, libmysql

I have been working on a project on a Linux operating system. I was using Qt for this purpose and was linking it to libmysqlclient to connect to mysql database. I had used the Mysql Connector-C for the connection.
Now I need to shift this project to Windows. Though everything works fine, I am unable to connect to the Mysql database. I guess the analogous library for windows will be libmysql.lib. But I am unable to use it with Qt. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
I would prefer using MinGW compiler though MSVC shall also do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a special reason that you use libmysqlclient? Qt has fine mysql drivers/plugins installed, which would make your code platform independent. I am quite sure, that everything you need is already included in the official qt binaries from Digia.

Comment: Yeah true. But I was a newbie with Qt and learnt this too late. So the rest of my code is already ready with libmysqlclient and it will be too difficult to edit them all over again I guess.

Comment: You use the MinGW? Then you need also the libmysql.dll. The .lib is MSVC, I think.

Comment: I've got both MinGW and MSVC. But I am unable to connect with either of them. I've got the libmysql.dll, but I can't link my project to it. Please help.

Comment: 'Help' is easy to say. Show some error messages. I personally am more interested in the MinGW stuff. Far less experience with MSVC. The .pro file is also of interest.